# how to extract data to C# variable from database

Tags: c#, sql-server

while trying to fetch value to c# variable from select query, got error

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select group1 from product where productname = @pn)", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pn", TextBox1.Text));

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();//got error

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        data = Convert.ToInt32(reader);//got error
    }    
}
```

Comment: Try `data = (SqlCommand)Int32.Parse("reader")`.

Comment: Please take a second and read up on how to ask an appropriate question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){ ...

Comment: You need to **open your connection** before executing the command ! Use `con.Open()` *before* the `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` call

Answer (score 2):

If you are to get a single value from database using [`ExecuteScalar()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) is the way to go.

Use like this;

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select group1 from product where productname = @pn)", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pn", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

    object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    data = Convert.ToInt32(value) 
}
```

Comment: object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();//error  Incorrect syntax near ')'. still same error appears.

Comment: using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select group1 from product where productname = @pn)", con))
     {

      cmd.Parameters.Add("@pn", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

      object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();///error occurs here at run time
      oldval = Convert.ToInt32(value);

      newval = oldval + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }                                                                                            am not sure what type of error it is??